# Why throwing exception in constructor results in a null reference?

Tags: c#, exception, object, constructor, null

Why throwing exception in constructor results in a null reference?
For example, if we run the codes below the value of teacher is null, while st.teacher is not (a Teacher object is created). Why?

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
      Test();
    }

    private static void Test()
    {
      Teacher teacher = null;
      Student st = new Student();
      try
      {
        teacher = new Teacher( "", st );
      }
      catch ( Exception e )
      {
        Console.WriteLine( e.Message );
      }
      Console.WriteLine( ( teacher == null ) );  // output True
      Console.WriteLine( ( st.teacher == null ) );  // output False
    }
  }

  class Teacher
  {
    public string name;
    public Teacher( string name, Student student )
    {
      student.teacher = this;
      if ( name.Length < 5 )
        throw new ArgumentException( "Name must be at least 5 characters long." );
    }
  }

  class Student
  {
    public Teacher teacher;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The constructor never completes, therefore the assignment never occurs. It's not that null is returned from the constructor (or that there's a "null object" - there's no such concept). It's just that you never assign a new value to `teacher`, so it retains its previous value.

For example, if you use:

```
Teacher teacher = new Teacher("This is valid", new Student());
Student st = new Student();
try
{
    teacher = new Teacher("", st);
}
catch (... etc ...)
```

... then you'll still have the "This is valid" teacher. The `name` variable still won't be assigned a value in that `Teacher` object though, as your `Teacher` constructor is missing a line such as:

```
this.name = name;
```

Comment: thanks for the great explanation, I edited "null object" in the question to "null reference".

Comment: Great explanation, also you're just proved that not initialized object in C# always holds «null». I began doubt in that because when I tried to use in Visual Studio an object that could be uninitialized in a certain conditions, but anyway it was checked checked for «null», and next used, the compiler shown an error about uninitialized variable. After I explicitly initialized the object with «null», the error disappeared. Thanks to you, now I know that it is just a bug of Visual Studio.

Comment: @Hi-Angel: Nope, it's not a bug. It's the difference between a *field* and a local variable. A field has a default value, and can be used without ever having been set - a local variable *cannot* be read until it's definitely assigned.

Answer (score 14):

Cause you're checking the *referencies*.

```
  try
  {
    teacher = new Teacher( "", st ); //this line raises an exception 
                                     // so teacher REMAINS NULL. 
                                     // it's NOT ASSIGNED to NULL, 
                                     // but just NOT initialized. That is.
  }
  catch ( Exception e )
  {
    Console.WriteLine( e.Message );
  }
```

but

```
public Teacher( string name, Student student )
{
  student.teacher = this;  //st.Teacher is assigned BEFORE exception raised.
  if ( name.Length < 5 )
    throw new ArgumentException( "Name must be at least 5 characters long." );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you throw an exception in a constructor, you break object's construction. So it's never finished and hence, there's no object to return. In fact, that assignment operator (`teacher = new Teacher( "", st );`) is never executed since exception breaks the calling stack.

And the Teacher constructor still writes a reference to itself (the object being constructed) into the Student object's property. But you should never try using this Teacher object afterwards, since it has not been constructed. It may result in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If `Foo` is a reference type, the statement `Foo = new FooType();` will construct an object and then, *after the constructor has completed*, store a reference into `Foo`.  If the constructor throws an exception, the code which would store the reference into `Foo` will be skipped without `Foo` having been written.

In cases where:

- A statement like the above occurs within a `try`/`catch` block
- The statement can be reached without `Foo` having been written beforehand.
- `Foo` a local variable defined in a context surrounding the `catch` block.
- It is possible for execution starting at the catch to reach a statement which reads `Foo` without its having written in after the `catch`.

The compiler will assume that the latter attempt to read `Foo` could be executed without `Foo` having been written, and will refuse compilation in that case.  The compiler will allow `Foo` to be read without having been written, however, if:

- `Foo` is a class field, or a field of a struct stored in a class field, a field of a struct stored in a field of a struct stored in a class field, etc.
- `Foo` is passed as an `out` parameter to a method (written in a language other than C#) that doesn't store anything to it, and the statement which reads `foo` would only be reachable if the method had returned normally rather than via exception.

In the former case, `Foo` will have a defined value of `null`.  In the latter case, the value of `Foo` will likely be null the first time it is created during the execution of a method; if re-created within a loop, it may contain `null` or the last value to written to it after the last time it was created; the standard is not specific about what will happen in that situation.

Note that if `FooType` has anything resembling a normal constructor, `Foo = new FooType();` will never *cause* `Foo` to become null if it wasn't before.  If the statement completes normally, `Foo` will hold a reference to an instance of exact type `FooType` to which no reference had previously existed anywhere in the universe; if it throws an exception, it will not affect `Foo` in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You are throwing the exception after the assignment
'student.teacher = this; //This line is executed
      if ( name.Length < 5 ) //This is checked and is true in the case specified
        throw new ArgumentException( "Name must be at least 5 characters long." );//BAM : Exception thrown here.'

So value of teacher is null (as exception thrown before completion of constructor), while st.teacher is not!

Answer (score -1):

Main job of the constructor is to initialize the object. If there is an exception in initialization itself then no point in having an object which is not properly initialized.
Hence throwing exception from a constructor results in null object.

Comment: This is not correct; it doesn't result in anything at all, as pointed out in other answers.