# Exception throw from constructor and what happen to instance and memory allocation?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I have class like this. ( This is just example)

```
    public class NewTest
    {
        public int I { get; set; }
        public NewTest()
        {                
            I = 10;
            throw new ApplicationException("Not Possible");
        }
    }
```

Now if I use class like this

```
 NewTest t = new NewTest();
```

In above line as NewTest constructor throw exception variable t never assign any value as before constuctor get complete it throw exception but as per test and also per other question ( [Why throwing exception in constructor results in a null reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119896/why-throwing-exception-in-constructor-results-in-a-null-reference)) object is created.

Now this object is created in Heap but it does not hold any root variable for reference so does it create problem for garbage collection ? or Is it memory leak of something ?

---

Following example help me to clear my confusion.
Another Example

```
 namespace ConsoleApplication1
 {
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        NewMethod();
        System.GC.Collect();
        Console.WriteLine("Completed");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void NewMethod()
    {
        Object obj = null;
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
            Console.ReadLine();
            NewTest t = new NewTest(out obj);
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception thrown");
        }

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
            Console.ReadLine();
            NewTest1 t = new NewTest1();
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception thrown");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
        Console.ReadLine();

        System.GC.Collect();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
        Console.ReadLine();           

    }
}

public class NewTest1
{
    public int I { get; set; }
    public NewTest1()
    {
        I = 10;
        throw new ApplicationException("Not Possible");
    }
}

public class NewTest
{
    public int I { get; set; }
    public NewTest(out Object obj)
    {
        obj = this;
        I = 10;
        throw new ApplicationException("Not Possible");
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: The GC really likes objects that are not referenced.  For all it cares, it thinks this Is the most efficient code you could ever write :)  Well, not counting it now also having to collect the exception object.  You are fretting over a non-existing problem here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Throwing exceptions in the constructor is not a problem to garbage collector, and it definitely does not result in memory leaks.

Although the memory allocated from the heap never makes it to your program, it is available to the internal implementation of the operator `new`, which takes care of ensuring that the newly created instance becomes eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: I accepted the answer. Even I get evidence through windbg and I will post that example in question so that will useful to understand the question well.

Answer (score 8):

The other answers are correct; I will add to them the fun fact that *finalizable objects whose constructor throws are still finalized*. That means that a finalizer can operate on an object whose constructor did not complete normally. **A finalizer must not assume that an object is initialized at the point when it is finalized**.  This is yet another in a long list of reasons why it is hard to write a correct finalizer.

Comment: Yes. I am agree with you @Eric Lippert. Your point on finalizer is also valid one that I think about but I thought I will try some other day. Thanks for your expert comment. I should allow up vote multiple time for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you look logically null is just a value which your reference could have. Your code is equal to

```
NewTest t = null;
t = new NewTest();->  the assignment never occurs because you throw exception
```

So the value for this reference is null, no problem for garbage collector.

Comment: I know that for variable t there is no problem but object actually allocated memory so that memory get pointed as there is no root.