# Is there any performance or safety benefit I'm missing to writing code this way?

Tags: c#, initialization

I currently am maintaining some legacy web app, and I frequently stumble on code like this:

```
Model modelObject = null;
modelObject = new Model(/*[whatever]*/);
return modelObject;
```

I would intuitively write either:

```
return new Model(/*[whatever]*/);
```

or:

```
Model modelObject = new Model(/*[whatever]*/);
// [anything implying modelObject]
return modelObject;
```

But I don't frankly understand why would one write it the first way, therefore here comes my question: Is there anything I'm missing that would go towards the first example in terms of **safety** or **performance**?

Comment: You should ask the person who wrote it

Comment: *Model modelObject = null;* because there are too many programmers that write random code until it works, not knowing what they are doing. I've seen `var lst =  new List<int>(); lst = SomeMethod();` (you are creating an object here and then discarding it because you are reassigning the variable)

Comment: In heavily refactored code it could be that the `Model modelObject = null;` case was actually used before this code got removed.

Comment: As for me, I assign value just before return for one reason only: I want to see (in debug, just point a variable with mouse), what I returning right before I return it, so I can tweak it. As of performance, I think roslyn is smart enough to compile first and second example to the same IL-code. Correct me, if I'm wrong.

Comment: Another opinion/guess... some people might prefer to declare all variables at the start of a function for clarity. In such a simple method it might not make sense, but in a complex method it could help understand the code better. And consistency with coding practices is important.

Comment: @xanatos that's the worst. I see that so often. It drives me crazy

Comment: It does create a known value. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119896/why-throwing-exception-in-constructor-results-in-a-null-reference)

Comment: Thank you @vasily.sib, then if the compiler compiles both codes to the same thing, it means there's no benefit in using one over the other *in terms of safety or performance* except maybe compiling-time for the *performance* part?

Comment: @Rafalon well, I have check generated IL-code, and can confirm, that `Release` build generate exactly same code. On `Debug` however there are some differences (extra ldloc/stloc instructions).

Answer (score 3):

In your example assigning `null` doesn't make any difference, and just a waste of printable characters.

The reason why you might want to assign `null`, is if there is branching or a situation where the value may not be set and/or you explicitly need to check for it because of an exception or alike.

e.g

```
string str = null;

if(somecondition)
   str = "set"

return str;
```

Comment: But even in this example, if `somecondition` isn't met, wouldn't `str` still be `null` if not initialized?

Comment: @Rafalon, in this case, `string str;` or `string str = null;` on the first line are not exactly equivalent; the former will give a compiler warning that you're using a possibly uninitialized value. The runtime behavior will be equivalent, though, but by explicitly initializing to `null` you're telling the compiler that you know it's a possibility and you're fine with it.

Comment: @TomasLycken I just tried it on tutorialspoint's coding ground, and it appears that it's more than a warning, it is indeed an error (`error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'str'`)

Comment: @Rafalon: It's only an error if you don't actually assign a value, in the example in the question (with `= null` removed) it would not produce an error, or even a warning.

Comment: @musefan: ...and that was *exactly* the point of my comment above...

Comment: @TomasLycken: Ok, I guess perhaps you were referring to the answer code as opposed to the question code example

Answer (score 0):

There might be lots of reasons why the code has ended up looking this way; if it's been version controlled from the start, and the people writing it were diligent in writing good commit messages, it's possible that you could learn something from reading the commit logs. It seems more likely to me, though, that it's just a sign that the code was authored by someone who was still learning.

That said, even if there might once have been a good reason the code looked like that, there is no good reason to let it stand that way today. Refactor away! :)

Comment: Whoever just downvoted: what do you think is bad about this answer?

Comment: *there is no good reason to let it stand that way today.* But there is the rule "don't touch what is working"... He can correct it only because he is refactoring.

Comment: Your answer is an opinion, and with opinion based answers I tend to vote based on if I agree with your opinion or not. (As there is no "factual" part to your answer it is not possible to vote based on correctness). In this case I disagree that it was just because someone was learning.

Comment: May I also suggest that instead of answering primarily opinion based question they should be closed instead.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann I specifically **bolded** the terms *performance* and *safety* but **you** edited it so it looks like primarily opinion based

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann: Re: someone still learning, I never said it *definitely* was - I said it *seems to me* it was. This is an attempt to give context, not to state a definitive truth.

Re: what to do about it today, as the code stands it is (as demonstrated by this question being asked) confusing its readers, while accomplishing nothing over the simplified approach. The OP specifically asks "is there any benefit I'm missing to writing code this way?" and I'm answering "no, there is not."

Comment: @TomasLycken: Firstly, my name isn't Micha. The point is that your answer is **your opinion only**, there is no facts. And to say there is no benefit to writing code like that, again is **your opinion**, others may see plenty of benefits to doing it

Comment: @musefan: Sorry that I tagged the wrong account. I disagree that this is just my opinion, given the context in the OP (safety, performance), but seeing as this question is about to be closed anyway, I guess it doesn't matter much. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Rafalon: I hope you learned what you hoped to learn, even if the question soon gets closed :)

Comment: @TomasLycken: Not sure how the code and proposed changes effect safety or performance? I am also baffled as to how you can't see that your answer is just an opinion. An "opinion" means that it is your view and that it might not be the same view as someone else. Without facts and proof then it can only be an opinion. If you started your answer with "I wrote this code and the reasons why is..." then that would be more factual. Although of course I would have to believe you first ;)

Comment: @TomasLycken I've used your comment to change the title of my question, as it seems this is what made it so bad